# Object of class ClassMuestra could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysqli, crud

Hola amigos bueno les cuento soy nueva programando en php, en este momento estoy haciendo un crud y cuando hago un registro me arroja este error Object of class ClassMuestra could not be converted to string ya revise el query y no lo encuentro me pueden ayudar porfavor

Comment: anexa el código que tengas para ayudarte

Comment: Buenos días  @dmgarcia33, como comenta esteban, coloca algo de tu código para que podamos ayudarte. Echa un vistazo también a [ask].

Comment: @estebanfabianpatiño muchas gracias por responder fue un descuido por que pense que en la base de datos la llave primaria era auto increment pero no lo estaba entonces me faltaba mandar un dato.